# C# insert image to database with class

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms, winforms

I want to save my image to database with class file, but I get an error in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` when i try to upload. I use bin datatype for image column.
this is my class code

```
    public int addclubs(string clubname, string president, string presidentID, string vicepresident, string vicepresidentID, string secretary, string secretaryID,
                          string clubdesc, DateTime established, Image images)
    {
        int status = 0;

        string insertSQL = "INSERT INTO Clubs(club_name,president,presidentID,vice_president,vice_presidentID,secretary,secretaryID,club_desc,established,image)" +
            "Values(@club,@prs,@prsID,@vc,@vcID,@sec,@secID,@clubdesc,@esb,@img)";
        Connect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@club", clubname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prs", president);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prsID", presidentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vc", vicepresident);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vcID", vicepresidentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec", secretary);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secID", secretaryID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clubdesc", clubdesc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@esb", established);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", images);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return status;
    }
```

here for the `private void btnRegRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```
                byte[] imagebt = null;
            FileStream fst = new FileStream(picUploadReg.ImageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fst);
            imagebt = br.ReadBytes((int)fst.Length);
            DateTime established = DateTime.Parse(dtpClubReg.Value.ToString());
            ctrls.addclubs(txtNameClubReg.Text, txtPresidentReg.Text, txtPresidentIDReg.Text, txtViceReg.Text, txtViceIDReg.Text, txtSecReg.Text, txtSecIDReg.Text, txtClubDescReg.Text, established,picUploadReg.Image);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `Image` is a class used to manipulate images, not an Image's data. To the database, an image is just a blob - a bunch of bytes. From C# you need to pass either a `byte[]` or `Stream` with those bytes.

Comment: @itsme86 This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    IOOP_Assignment.MyClass.controllers.addclubs(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, System.DateTime, System.Drawing.Image) in controllers.cs
    IOOP_Assignment.Register.btnRegRegister_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Register.cs
    [External Code]
    IOOP_Assignment.Program.Main() in Program.cs

Comment: The good news is that you appear to have those bytes in `imagebt` (which you're not using yet), so you can change your method's signature to accept `byte[]` instead of `Image` and pass that variable.

Comment: @YogiSeptiargy But what is the exception?!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes the problem is i cant change my datatype into BLOB

Comment: @itsme86 System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.Bitmap to a known managed provider native type.'

Comment: I suspect you mistook the obsolete `image` type name used way back in 2000-2005 for the .NET Image type? They aren't related at all. SQL Server has a `varbinary(max)` type that 15+ years ago was called `image`. In fact [that name is marked for deletion in the future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Don't use those names, and change the current fields to use the correct names. In any case, this is just a BLOB storing bytes.

Comment: Yes thank you all, my problem solved. My data type should be in `varbinary(max)` 
and I change my method from `image` to `byte[]` then using the `imagebt`

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against saving the image itself in your table. You might want to save or create a copy of your image in a folder inside your application and a reference to the image in the table. This is much easier and more efficient from my experience.
I would glady supply you with the code once I get home as I'm on mobile.